# CockroachDB is generating big ids when records are inserted via spring

Tags: spring-boot, cockroachdb

I am creating an application that uses cockroachDB but when I insert any new record , cockroachDB generates very big ids like '600372119629037569', is there a way to shorten these Ids?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `serial_normalization` setting to `sql_sequence`.
Just be aware that this can decrease performance. Is it important for the IDs to be small?

See: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/serial.html#modes-of-operation